Zorn's lemma: counterexample to chain with upper bound?
The premise required for invoking Zorn's lemma is that every chain in $X$ have an upper bound. So that makes me wonder: what is a good example of a poset $X$ for which that property is false? That is to say, what is an example of a poset $X$ and a chain $Y$ in $X$ s.t. Y does not have an upper bound?
For example, my first idea was $X=$"all bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$" and $Y=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(0,n).$ Would that count?

You mean like $[0,1)$ with the chain ${1-\frac1n}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Proper subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$; consider the subgroups of rationals whose denominators are divisible only by the first $n$ primes.

Your example is OK, but there are simpler ones. Probably the simplest is the natural numbers with their usual ordering. @MPWs example is order-isomorphic to that.

There are loads and loads of examples. I like Arturo's example a lot, because it's an example of a Zorn-type fact failing. In particular, you can prove with Zorn's lemma that any unital ring has a maximal proper ideal. But the group $\Bbb Q$ has no maximal proper subgroup, indicating that the poset of proper subgroups of $\Bbb Q$ cannot satisfy the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma.

@IzaakvanDongen, I agree, Arturo's example is excellent. But what do you mean by "it's an example of a Zorn-type fact failing"?

I mean what I said afterwards. The following is true (because of Zorn): "every unital ring has a maximal proper ideal". This is not true: "every group has a maximal proper subgroup". This is an example of a place "in nature" where a plausible-sounding statement that might be proved by Zorn's lemma is not true, because the hypothesis of Zorn's lemma fails. I think that's what makes it a nice example.

@IzaakvanDongen Or for that matter, "every ring has a maximal proper ideal"...
